# How to check if all views inside my layout which contains multiple webviews are fully loaded

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview, android-webview

I have a `RecyclerView` layout and multiple items are displayed each using `CardView`. Each `CardView` has one `WebView` to display html content. The layout itself loading fine. However the `WebView` is visible immediately along with other views and starts loading content. This makes the view appear loading and adjusting the height etc.

How can I know when entire `RecyclerView` is fully loaded and visible so that I can make it visible?

P.S. The content is html content already fetched from server, so not sure why WebView takes time to display while others like TextView are shown immediately.

Comment: Webview is heavy. Can you try https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview although this directly does not answer your question

Comment: I am afraid the content formatting will lost by using that. The content is usually html content posted on website with full fledged html editor. The said html-textview plugin supports only few elements. Anyway, I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: you can modify by writing custom tag handlers. Any way looking for a better option